# firebase deploy painfully slow due to API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com which is not even required

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

There's no job scheduler in cloud scheduler then why firebase cli is showing `required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled` whenever I deploy any function? And it's taking upto a minute to finish this *required API..is enabled* task.

[image]

Command: `firebase deploy --only functions`

Output:

```
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function addUsertoDB(asia-east2)...
+  scheduler: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions[addUsertoDB(asia-east2)]: Successful update operation.
```

Comment: I suggest filing an issue with Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support